# React - How to store data without Redux

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and creating a simple app. The only data I need to store globally is a user object, and I would like to avoid using Redux if possible. I'm having a hard time finding info on the best way to do this + tutorials and examples. Will using a [Provider](https://medium.com/@joomiguelcunha/react-patterns-you-should-know-da86568372fa) from the Context API be suitable?

Comment: Depends on the amount of data? What kind of data.

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin not much, just an object with an accesstoken, user id, name, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great open source library called [Unstated](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated). It still uses a component architecture for deciding on who has access to the data, but it's a lot simpler (IMO) than redux. You could also just store something on the *window* object just for testing, but it's a really bad idea to do that in production.

Comment: thanks for sharing. i checked it out, but ended up implementing the provider/context API instead!